# Using React-Query QueryCache from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a component that uses `useQuery` from React Query like this:

```
const { data } = useQuery(
    ["products", selectedStore],
    fetchProductsByStoreId
)
```

`selectedStore` is a local state variable that can be changed from the UI, triggering a request to the API for new products. My problem is, that I also need to use the data from the request in another component, preferably via `queryCache.getQueryData`, but to do this, I need to provide a key, that is not only the string `"Products"` but the whole array `["products", selectedStore]`.

The other component does not have access to `selectedStore`, so my question is, is there a way the other component can access this query data without hoisting `selectedStore` to global state? I would like to keep the data in the `queryCache` and not hoist it either.

Comment: Since selectedStore is UI client state we need to store in global state or nearest possible component hierarchy via context API, zustand or redux etc, Then from other component we can fetch the cached data.

Comment: Ya u need to follow what raja mentioned or make the cache key just `products` and the cache will only have the latest data. But then u sorta loose the benefits caching and react-query.

Answer (score 5):

So if you want to retrieve data for a specific key, you need the (full) key. Moving your client state up to the tree to make it accessible to all component that need it, or, if necessary to global client state seems like the best solution.

`queryClient.getQueryData` also supports query filters, so you can match on the queryKey with a custom match function if you want. But without knowing what the `selectedStore` is, if there are multiple entries in the cache, e.g. `["products", 1]` and `["products", 2]`, how would you know which one to use?

Also note that `queryClient.getQueryData` is an imperative operation that doesn't create a subscription - so if the underlying data changes, that component will not be re-rendered. Only `useQuery` or a custom subscription (via `queryClient.getQueryCache().subscribe`) can do that.

Answer (score 1):

To put param in the routing is another method to share data between components, but React.Context is better suit for it.